# Correct notation for taking the element-wise square root of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

As the title says, I'm pretty confused how I can, in correct mathematical notation, note that the square root of each element of a matrix needs to be taken. If

$$ A \triangleq \left[ \begin{array}\\ x_1, x_2 \\ x_3, x_4 \end{array} \right] $$

what is the correct notation for $\sqrt{A}$ where $$ \sqrt{A} \triangleq \left[ \begin{array}\\ \sqrt{x_1}, \sqrt{x_2} \\ \sqrt{x_3}, \sqrt{x_4} \end{array} \right] ?$$

Essentially, what is the correct symbol I attach to $A$ to indicate element-wise square roots are to be taken?

Comment: Different contexts will use different notation for this idea. [Sometimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Analogous_operations), the notation $A^{\circ 1/2}$ is used.

Comment: Great!  Also good to know what I'm referring to is the *Hadamard root*.  If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this is referred to as the [Hadamard root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Analogous_operations) and is referred to with notation $A^{\circ 1/2}$.